# How can I run MDX queries against a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, mdx, olap, business-intelligence, olap-cube

If I have a PostgreSQL server running with my data already structured in facts and dimensions, how can I run MDX queries against it?

Let's suppose each row in the fact table is a sale, so the fact table has the following columns: id, product_id, country_id and amount.

And the dimension tables are very simple: product_id and product_name, and country_id and country_name.

How should I proceed to be able to run MDX queries against this data? I tried downloading Mondrian but I found it very hard to use.

Please keep in mind I am not a developer, so my technical skills are limited; I work at an investment fund and I want to be able to run more powerful analysis on our data sets. But I do have some basic knowledge on SQL and I can code a little bit in Ruby.

Comment: you need to create an olap cube before you can write any mdx. Therefore you need to transform your database into this new structure. Microsoft use an analysis services server to host such a structure so does Mondrian and icCube do a free version.

Comment: Hi whytheq, thanks for your answer. Could you ellaborate more on it?

Comment: I just write `mdx` against cubes that already exist. So we have a warehouse  built using a `Kimball` model star schema - then using SQL Server Analysis Services the cubes are set up (specifying all required relationships) and built.

Comment: I see. How can I set up an OLAP cube?

Comment: If you are serious about creating some cubes then you need to either ask your company for some money so that you can get the required software such as SQL-Server Analysis Services or use a free olap server such as the one provided by icCube - learn how to use the software you choose and then point it at your data...

Comment: Whyteq, I work with a rather small team. It is basically me in charge of operations plus a few investment partners. Is there no "easy way" to setup data cubes? And by that I mean "easy enough to setup by myself".

Answer (score 8):

As you already have a DWH (data warehouse) in PostgreSQL which contains dimension tables and fact tables, now you are two steps from building simple analysis solution. The solution I recommend consists of:

- **DWH:** PostgreSQL
- **OLAP server**: [Mondrian OLAP](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/olap.php) ([OLAP schema workbench tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mondrian/files/schema%20workbench/))
- **Analysis tool:** [Saiku Analysis application](http://community.meteorite.bi/?cedownload) (you can preview [Saiku demo here](http://demo.saikuanalytics.com/))

Steps:

1. Download the [OLAP schema workbench tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mondrian/files/schema%20workbench/). Using this tool you can create Mondrian OLAP schema easily on the top of the existing tables (dimensions, facts) of your DWH.
2. Once you create the OLAP schema, download the [Saiku Analysis application](http://community.meteorite.bi/?cedownload), configure it to use your OLAP schema and your DWH
3. Run Saiku - you can run MDX queries on the DWH or do ad-hoc data analysis by drag&drop of measures (amount, etc.) and dimensions (product name, country name).

Comment: mzy, thanks very much for your answer, I'll try your steps and comment back here. =)

Answer (score 0):

Still today year 2023 PostgreSQL is doesn't have anything like Microsoft Analysis Services (Tabular or Multidimensional) which can pre-calculate data on different dimension levels to speedup the query time.

Currently the solutions are to use 3dparty tools which are processing your DWH and making an OLAP database. In this case you will not be able to use fancy popular front ends like PowerBI as the connector probably will be missing, or even the software provides the connector it will be only usable from PowerBI Desktop and not the PowerBI Service. This makes the roll-outs and maintenance even harder when it comes for production architectures.

My experience is not so good while having PostgreSQL with millions of data into tables and using PowerBI direct query, so defiantly this would be the best feature if PostgreSQL ever built such a thing natively.